# The Word for 'Ball' Pre-Colonisation

Tags: phonology, phonetics, historical-linguistics, vowels, malay

What I've found is that word-final /a/ in native Malay words and words up to the time of the Portuguese invasion (16-17th century) undergo reduction, e.g.:

```
/a/ → [ə] / __#

Mata (eye) - [matə]
Kura-kura (tortoise) - [kurə kurə]
Gila (crazy) - [gilə]

Jendela (janela, window) - [dʒəndelə]
Kemeja (camisa, shirt) - [kəmedʒə]
Tinta (tinta, ink) - [tintə]
```

Non-native words retain /a/, e.g.:

```
Sfera (sphere) - [sfera]
Koma (coma) - [koma]
Tuala (towel) - [tuʷala]
```

Surprisingly, the vowel in 'bola' (ball) does not undergo change.

```
Bola (ball) - [bola]
```

Based on the retention of the word-final /a/, we could arguably say that 'bola' is a foreign word.

If so, what might the native word for such a basic word be? If not, why is the vowel not reduced?

Comment: *bola* very much looks like a loan word, either from Portuguese (wiktionary adheres to this hypothesis) or later from English *ball*.

Comment: @jknappen Based on the phonological rule, it should have entered Malay later than Portuguese loan words.